# Minecraft Hamachi Server Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi, minecraft-java-edition-server

One day I went on my Hamachi server and it's the wrong map terrain & the spawn point had changed. Minecraft Server.exe keeps saying:

```
[WARNING] Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded?
```

I haven't exceeded 600 blocks, and I have enough RAM for 20 players on at a time (1GB RAM). Only 2 people have played on at a time, and 3 total players have played on the original world. What happened, and how do I get the map the way it used to be?

Comment: 20 players on 1gb of ram? 1gb of ram is barely enough to run Windows 7.

Comment: Furthermore, you're using *Hamachi* of all things. Hamachi's notorious for using far more resources than necessary, and then *still* not working. You'd be better off renting server space.

Comment: Well, if the spawn point and the terrain are completely different, there's a good possibility that that's a new world. You might want to check if you just suffered data loss.

Comment: Well, this is why we don't use netbooks to run minecraft servers, they can barely even run the client!

Comment: Perhaps someone tried to worldedit 6 million blocks of TNT and set them off, then left? :]

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the map with some map editor (mcedit) and see if you can see any of your old constructions or not.  If you can't, you've lost everything (data loss, probably).

If you can, you might want to set the spawn location to where it originally was.  I've seen a couple of scenarios where there was some data loss and the spawn point changed, but the mapped remained the same.